# A positive formula for the dimensions of homogeneous components of free Lie algebras

Tags: co.combinatorics, lie-algebras

The homogeneous component of degree $k$ in the free Lie algebra $\mathfrak{Lie}(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ in $n$ letters is of dimension $$g_n(k)=\frac{1}{k}\sum_{d|k}\mu(d)n^{k/d}.$$ This is also the number of [Lyndon words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyndon_word) of length $k$ in $n$ letters, and of a few other things...

**Question:** Is there a *positive* formula for this number?

As an aside,

**Question:** Is there a corresponding formula for the dimensions of the homogeneous components of the [free Lie triple system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_system) on $n$ letters?

Comment: Perhaps you meant the mu function instead of the phi function and n instead of m?  In any case, I don't see a reason to expect a positive formula here; look at the case when n is prime.

Comment: I think the m's in your formula should be n's.  Also, what is a "positive" formula?

Comment: I've fixed the formula, which was messed up from looking at too many places with different notations! @Qiaochu: to be honest, I do not expect there is a positive formula, but I enjoy being surprised! @Andy: a sum of positive numbers, for example, would be a 'positive formula'.

Comment: Er, whoops; I meant the case where k is prime.  You get (n^k - n)/k and there's really no sensible way around that minus sign that I can see.  

Comment: Well, $n^k-n=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(n^{i+1}-n^i)$ is a positive formula... Of course, 'positive formula' is not really well defined!

Comment: Andy- positive formulae are like pornography, I know them when I see them.  In general it's a sum where all the terms are positive and hopefully in bijection with known sets.

Comment: @Ben: your comment really confuses me... since for a basis of the free Lie algebra we can take Lyndon words (a very combinatorial object), the above formula can be thought of as a sum of one term which has a clear combinatorial meaning!

Comment: I second Vladimir's comment.  I'm also confused: as Mariano mentions, Lyndon words (or any Hall set in the free magma, for that matter, as in chapter II of Bourbaki's Lie groups and Lie algebras) are a basis for the free Lie algebra.  Why isn't this a "positive formula"?  I guess the point must really be the second question about triple systems?

Comment: Since the two questions are unrelated (at least, the answer to the triple system one is pretty disjoint to all the remainder), I'd encourage moving it to a separate question. (And then move the answer there too.)

Comment: In Bourbaki there's a formula for multigraded components (i.e., for the finer grading  in $\mathbf{Z}^n$ where one counts the number of each variable). This yields a decomposition of this number into a sum of positive numbers (each of which being also described by a formula involving Möbius).

Comment: @YCor, I am frankly quite amazed at the idea that the questions about Lie algebras and Lie triple systems could be viewed as unrelated and disjoint. The answer by Vladimir (which was exactly the one I wanted to hear 10 years ago :-) ) shows that they are very much connected: one is half of the other.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Of course I never said they're "unrelated and disjoint", they're definitely related. All my point is (1) I think Vladimir's answer completely settles one of your questions, and should therefore be accepted, and (2) at the same time that the first question should remain open rather than considered settled. (Of course you are free to disagree with (2) and consider that $g_n(k)=\mathbb{1}_{2\mathbf{Z}}(k)g_n(k)+\mathbb{1}_{2\mathbf{Z}+1}(k)g_n(k)$ is an interesting positive decomposition.)

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't answer the question, but might still be of interest to you.  Let $V$ be the $n$-dimensional vector space spanned by your $n$ letters.

The vector space $V^{\otimes k}$ has a natural $S_k$ action.  There exists an $S_k$ module, which I will denote $\text{Lie}(k)$, such that the $k$th homogenous component of the free Lie algebra on $V$ is isomorphic to

$V^{\otimes k} \otimes_{S_k} \text{Lie}(k)$.

And this module has dimension $(k-1)!$.  This wont help you with the dimensions you want, but I think that it's interesting.

If you want to read more then you need to learn about operads, and in particular the Lie operad.

If you just want to know the $S_k$-module structure on $\text{Lie}(k)$ then it can be given as follows:
Let $C_k$ be a subgroup of $S_k$ generated by a $k$-cycle.  Let $W$ be a 'primitive' representation of $C_k$.  (this requires a primitive $k$th root of unity in your field).
Then the module we are looking for is $W$ induced up to $S_k$.

This last bit is a bit mysterious to me.

Comment: This might not be an answer to OP's question but it answers a question I had about the dimension of that module, so +1

Answer (score 2):

For your question about Lie triple systems:

In my article "Veronese powers of operads and pure homotopy algebras" joint with Martin Markl and Elisabeth Remm, Eur. J. Math. 6 (2020), 829-863 (https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s40879-019-00351-6), it is established that the operad of Lie triple system is isomorphic to the operad of odd arity components of the Lie operad. Since the free algebra is obtained by evaluation of the corresponding Schur functor, it follows that the dimensions of homogeneous components of the free Lie triple system are equal to the dimensions of odd degree homogeneous components of the free Lie algebra on the same generators.

Answer (score 1):

Now, to the matter of "positive formulas".

Classical result of Kraskiewicz and Weyman (preprint W. Kraskiewicz, J. Weyman. Algebra of Invariants and the Action of a Coxeter Element. Math. Inst. Copernicus Univ. Chopina, Torun (1987), published W. Kraskiewicz, J. Weyman. Algebra of invariants and the action of a Coxeter element. Bayreuth. Math. Schr., 63 (2001)) proves that the multiplicity of the Specht module $S^{\lambda}$ in $\mathrm{Lie}(n)$ is given by an elegant combinatorial formula: it is equal to the dimension of standard Young tableaux of shape $\lambda$ and major index congruent to $1$ modulo $n$. Recall that the major index is equal to the sum of all $i$ such that $i+1$ is strictly below $i$ in the tableau. By Schur-Weyl duality, this means that the irreducible representation $S^\lambda(V)$ of $GL(V)$ appears in the free Lie algebra generated by $V$ with that same multiplicity, the major index. Since dimensions of irreducible representations of $GL(V)$ admit well-known positive formulas, you get a positive formula for the dimension of the homogeneous component of the free Lie algebra.